# What is threshold to get ban on asking questions?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

I have been registered with Physics SE for almost two months, I am not a physicist (programmer) and here not to get my homework done, but more of curious person. I have asked 8 questions so far, 3 zero score 5 positive. [One of questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133263/what-distance-does-one-travels-in-his-lifetime) is closed due to lack of effort, [one is duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/131810/what-makes-us-move-in-time).
Today when I wanted to ask a question I got a warning:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a
>   good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

After [reading that to get unbanned to ask questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) I have go contribute in other ways (presumedly answer questions which I would rather not as I am incompetent in physics).

Before I ask anymore questions (and possibly get banned), I wanted to know **what is the threshold of getting banned from asking more questions?**

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8851/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's secret, and that message is sent rather early on in most cases so you have plenty of time to improve.

If you seem to actively be trying to improve, by reading the policies and cross checking, it shouldn't hit you.