# Are the criteria for an automatic question ban known?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

I’m asking because I noticed a member who has asked five questions, all of which have been significantly downvoted (on average, worse than -7), but who has not received a ban. I thought that members who consistently ask badly-received questions got some temporary suspension of their right to ask more questions.

Comment: No, the criteria are not public, to mitigate people gaming the b mechanism. It's worth examining how out of line those scores are with respect to the historical record, though.

Comment: How do you know they have not received an automatic question ban? The automated bans are *not* suspensions (the users can still vote, edit, etc., just not ask (or answer in the case of answer bans)) and are not visible to non-moderators on the user profile.

Comment: The other thing to know about the automatic bans is that when first imposed they time-out. Affected users can simply wait long enough and try again. Though I don't recall seeing it in black and white, I assume that they time-outs get longer if the ban is re-imposed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6116/2451

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks, I didn’t understand the distinction but now I do.

Comment: @Qmechanic I agree that this should be closed as a duplicate of that. Ugh. Now I’ve asked a bad question!

Comment: @G.Smith Four more to go ;-)

Comment: ...what is both a weak and an unfair concept. Security by obscurity, wonderful.